# Java object instanceof class A only

Tags: java

```
B extends B1, B1 extends B2, ... Bn extends A

B b = new B();
A a = new A();
```

a instanceof A => true, 
b instanceof A => true

But i want to know the direct instance of A only.

Comment: can you please further explain it what you mean by direct instance

Comment: what about interfaces?

Comment: isDirectInstance(a,A)-> true,  isDirectInstance(b,A)-> false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why don't you compare with the class?

```
public class ClassTest {

    class A{

    }

    class B extends A{

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassTest t = new ClassTest();
        A a = t.new B();

        System.out.println(a instanceof B); //true
        System.out.println(a instanceof A); //true

        System.out.println(a.getClass().equals(B.class)); //true
        System.out.println(a.getClass().equals(A.class)); //false
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use A.getClass() to get the Class name of the object. Once you have the class name, you can build your directInstance logic

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your object has the same class object as `A.class`.

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
System.out.println(a.getClass().equals(A.class)); //will display true
System.out.println(b.getClass().equals(A.class)); //will display false
```